# nslookup from another name server

Tags: networking, dns, nslookup

I need help figuring out why my DNS queries are being refused.

So this works:

[image]

And this does not work:

[image]

I can perform a DNS lookup of `aiit.or.kr` from Google DNS (8.8.8.8) however I can't perform the lookup from other servers (the one I have in the below example is a MIT nameserver).

I have a friend who can perform this search with MIT's nameserver on his machine but I cannot perform it on mine (he is on a different router/network than me). What could be causing the DNS query to be refused? Is this something to do with my ISP or a router configuration that I need to set? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

so I went to a hotel nearby and am borrowing their wifi and I am able to perform see below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5IwC.png)

this is very interesting to me, because it pretty much narrows it down to something on my home network. I have no idea though what what could be causing it.

Thank you again for looking at this. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: A firewall is a possible culprit.

Comment: I get the exact same results when I type the command `www.aiit.or.kr n0dscb.akamaiedge.net`.  What exactly is your question? **I have no DNS problems.**  It sounds like this "DNS" server isn't actually a DNS server.  It wasn't aware of google.com

Comment: Where did you get this "MIT server" from, and why do you expect it to answer these queries?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - That isn't the author's problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, please see my update to the post above. My goal of this post is just trying to explore nslookup features. I think its neat and useful to see the DNS query from my router to aiit.or.kr (over wireshark) and I wanted to see the DNS query from another name server (such as mit's). However, whenever I perform my experiment, (that is, asking n0dscb.akamaiedge.net to perform a DNS query on my behalf) I get errors/timeouts as mentioned above. This appears to be common to both my home network and your home network. so I am trying to figure out what might be inhibiting these basic commands.

Comment: n0dscb.akamaiedge.net has port 53 open, so it could be a DNS server, -->curl -kv n0dscb.akamaiedge.net:53
*   Trying 88.221.81.192...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to n0dscb.akamaiedge.net (88.221.81.192) port 53 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: n0dscb.akamaiedge.net:53
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: @CakeMaster - We expect practical problems.  If it's not even a DNS server you cannot expect it to work.

Comment: @ramhound It's possible you overlooked the word "posssible" in my comment.

Comment: Was simply letting the author know what wasn’t the case

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, because the DNS server you found is not a resolver. It does not handle recursive queries – it is an authoritative server, which only answers queries for those domains which it directly hosts.

(It's like how you can't take any random HTTP webserver and use it as an HTTP proxy: that's not its job and it will refuse the request. *Some* DNS servers, such as 8.8.8.8, are configured to act as resolvers – i.e. DNS proxies – but that doesn't mean all of them are.)

If the same address works for your friend, then I suspect that *their* ISP is actually intercepting all DNS queries, and redirecting them to the same server no matter which address you're querying. (Some ISPs do that.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What you said about the ISP does make sense. I tried this on a hotel wifi (presumably a different ISP) and was able to work (i updated my post with that info). Thanks again :)

Comment: Also! I would upvote your answer but I don't have a reputation yet.

Comment: Could you please connect to that same hotel WiFi and and try a `nslookup google.com 203.0.113.1` as well as `nslookup google.com 198.51.100.51`, then update with the results

Comment: unfortunately I cannot. I tried it from my home network and I get a similar timeout message as I have before.

Comment: Then ask your friend to test it on his machine (the one where the "MIT" server also worked).